# Wordpress・CakePHP連動のRewriteRuleの記述方法

Tags: cakephp, wordpress, .htaccess

いつもお世話になっています。

CakePHPで運営されているサイトの一部にWordpressを導入したいを思っています。

CakePHPで
http://www.test.test/note/memo
このようなURLで動作しているページがあるとします。

```
Router::connect('/note/:memo_id', array('controller' => 'front_note', 'action' => 'index'), array('pass' => array('memo_id')));
```

ここに、
http://www.test.test/note/memo/blog
というページを作り、『一番最後に「blog」と付いている場合＝Wordpressページ』と判別させたいのです。

Wordpressは/webroot/wordpress/として設置済みです。
Wordpress側では、カテゴリ「memo」を作成し、スラッグを設定、パーマリンクで「/%category%/blog」とする事で対応しています。

また、設定・一般で以下のように設定しました。
Wordpressアドレス＝http://www.test.test/wordpress
サイトアドレス＝http://www.test.test/note

次にwebrootのhtaccessを以下のように追記しました。

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/note/(.*)/blog$　← 追記
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/(.*)/blog$　← 追記
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

こうした時、
http://www.test.test/note/memo
は平常通りCakePHPで作成したページが表示されるのですが、
http://www.test.test/note/memo/blog
はNotFoundになります、
http://www.test.test/wordpress/memo/blog
は表示されます。

htaccess部分の書き方が悪いのだろうなと思い調べて試してみたのですが、巧く行きません。
大変お手数お掛け致しますが、不足部分ご教授お願いできませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

先に `/note/*/blog` をWordPressへルーティングすればよいでしょう。

```
# /note/*/blog を WordPressへルーティング
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/note/(.+)/blog(/|$)
RewriteRule ^ wordpress/index.php [L]

# /wordpressを除外してCakePHPへルーティング
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```